# Iterate through each value of list in order, starting at random value

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, iteration

Given the following code:

```
length = 10
numbers = [x for x in range(length)]    
start_index = randint(0,length-1)
# now output each value in order from start to start-1 (or end)
# ex. if start = 3 --> output = 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2
# ex if start = 9 ---> output = 9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

What is the best / simplest / most pythonic / coolest way to iterate over the list and print each value sequentially, beginning at start and wrapping to start-1 or the end if the random value were 0.

Ex. `start = 3` then output = `3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2`

I can think of some ugly ways (try, except IndexError for example) but looking for something better. Thanks!

EDIT: made it clearer that start is the index value to start at

Comment: Try using the remainder operation: `(start+i)%10`

Comment: @NightShadeQueen, calling `randint()` for each item will result in a random `list`.

Comment: Do you want to have the output array start with `numbers.index(start)` or `numbers[start]`?

Comment: I was thinking start would be the index to start at, so numbers[start].

Comment: If anyone is curious about performance, I found that slicing and the deque rotate method were significantly faster than others (and about the same speed with deque being slightly faster). I would be curious as to _why_ if anyone knows!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> start = randint(0, len(numbers))
>>> start
1
```

You can use list slicing then iterate over that

```
>>> numbers[start:] + numbers[:start]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
```

You can also use the modulus `%` operator in a list comprehension

```
>>> [numbers[i%len(numbers)] for i in range(start, start + len(numbers))]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use the `%` (modulo) operator.

```
length = 10
numbers = [x for x in range(length)]    
start = randint(0, length)

for i in range(length):
    n = numbers[(i + start) % length]
    print(n)
```

Answer (score 3):

> What is the best / simplest / most pythonic / coolest way ...

You can use [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) and its [`rotate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque.rotate) function, like this

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> d = deque(numbers)
>>> d.rotate(-9)
>>> d
deque([9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
>>> 
>>> d = deque(numbers)
>>> d.rotate(-2)
>>> d
deque([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to iterate over the list with simple conditional loops

```
i = start
while(True):
    print i,    
    if i==numbers[-1]:  # If it's the last number
        i=numbers[0]
    else:
        i += 1
    if i==start:  # One iteration is over
        break
```

This will print `3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2`